# Por que Visual studio no encuentra mi servidor?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2019

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto pero al querer probarlo no encuentra mi servidor local.
Cuando le doy a iniciar proyecto me da el siguiente mensaje:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
namespace CapaDatos
{
    public class CD_Conexion
    {
        private SqlConnection Conexion = new SqlConnection("Server=LAPTOP-9CE06N23/SQLEXPRESS;DataBase= Practica;Integrated Security=true");

        public SqlConnection AbrirConexion()
        {
            if (Conexion.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                 Conexion.Open();
            return Conexion;
        }

        public SqlConnection CerrarConexion()
        {
            if (Conexion.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                Conexion.Close();
            return Conexion;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: e hiciste lo que dice el cartel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recuerda que la version `express` del `sql server` por defecto no permite conexiones remotas, sino que debes habilitarlo

[How to Enable Remote Connections in SQL Server 2014/2012/2008](https://www.top-password.com/blog/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server/)

El primer paso seria habilitar la opcion desde el management studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero tambien debes validar que el protocolo este habilitado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ultimo valida que el puerto `1433` (usado por defecto por sql server) este habilitado en el `firewall de windows`